# Why is background color not snapping even with displaying: inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I am sorry if I am missing something obvious but I have no idea why it is not snapping like the other things on my page.

```css
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9 !important;
}

.featured-products {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

.featured-header {
  font-size: 1rem !important;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 340px;
  margin-right: 340px;
  color: #3c1c64;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="featured-products">
  <h2 class="featured-header"><strong>Try our newest creation, the Quaruntine Cookie Pack with our most famous flavors!</strong></h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'snapping'?

Comment: Staying right around the text area instead of the whole width

Comment: Can you also show an example of a element that does match your desired behaviour, since you mention that some things do 'snap' around the text area on your site.

Comment: you need to set a fixed width or else it will inherit width from it's parent which is 100%

Answer (score 0):

Is the code below something you would expect?

```css
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9 !important;
}

.featured-products {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%; /* To make sure it will size correctly on smaller screens */
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

.featured-header {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #3c1c64;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-products">
  <h2 class="featured-header"><strong>Try our newest creation, the Quaruntine Cookie Pack with our most famous flavors!</strong></h2>
</div>
```